# NoSuchMethodError on creating a web service client

Tags: java, apache-axis, webservice-client, nosuchmethoderror

I'm new to java and web services and `axis2`. I recently created a web service using some tutorials. When I first follow the tutorial eclipse let me create a client. But when I try to create a new project and a new web service client it gives `NoSuchMethodError`. Which exactly looks like this:

> Exception occurred while code generation for WSDL  :
>   java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   javax.wsdl.Operation.getExtensionAttributes()Ljava/util/Map;
>       java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at org.eclipse.jst.ws.axis2.consumption.core.utils.WSDL2JavaGenerator.getAxisService(WSDL2JavaGenerator.java:379)
>       at org.eclipse.jst.ws.axis2.consumption.core.command.Axis2ClientCodegenCommand.execute(Axis2ClientCodegenCommand.java:94)
>       at org.eclipse.wst.command.internal.env.core.fragment.CommandFragmentEngine.runCommand(CommandFragmentEngine.java:419)
>       at org.eclipse.wst.command.internal.env.core.fragment.CommandFragmentEngine.visitTop(CommandFragmentEngine.java:359)
>       at org.eclipse.wst.command.internal.env.core.fragment.CommandFragmentEngine.moveForwardToNextStop(CommandFragmentEngine.java:254)
>       at org.eclipse.wst.command.internal.env.ui.widgets.SimpleCommandEngineManager$6.run(SimpleCommandEngineManager.java:294)
>       at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext.runInCurrentThread(ModalContext.java:369)
>       at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext.run(ModalContext.java:313)
>       at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.run(WizardDialog.java:934)
>       at org.eclipse.wst.command.internal.env.ui.widgets.SimpleCommandEngineManager.runForwardToNextStop(SimpleCommandEngineManager.java:264)
>       at org.eclipse.wst.command.internal.env.ui.widgets.WizardPageManager.runForwardToNextStop(WizardPageManager.java:91)
>       at org.eclipse.wst.command.internal.env.ui.widgets.WizardPageManager.performFinish(WizardPageManager.java:262)
>       at org.eclipse.wst.command.internal.env.ui.widgets.DynamicWizard.performFinish(DynamicWizard.java:380)
>       at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.finishPressed(WizardDialog.java:742)
>       at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.buttonPressed(WizardDialog.java:373)
>       at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.Dialog$2.widgetSelected(Dialog.java:618)
>       at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:227)
>       at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:66)
>       at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:938)
>       at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:3682)
>       at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3293)
>       at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.runEventLoop(Window.java:820)
>       at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:796)
>       at org.eclipse.ui.actions.NewWizardAction.run(NewWizardAction.java:182)
>       at org.eclipse.jface.action.Action.runWithEvent(Action.java:498)
>       at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(ActionContributionItem.java:546)
>       at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.access$2(ActionContributionItem.java:490)
>       at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem$5.handleEvent(ActionContributionItem.java:402)
>       at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:66)
>       at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:938)
>       at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:3682)
>       at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3293)
>       at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runEventLoop(Workbench.java:2389)
>       at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Workbench.java:2353)
>       at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$4(Workbench.java:2219)
>       at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$4.run(Workbench.java:466)
>       at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:289)
>       at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:461)
>       at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
>       at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:106)
>       at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:169)
>       at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:106)
>       at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:76)
>       at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:363)
>       at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:176)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:508)
>       at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:447)
>       at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1173)
>       Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.wsdl.Operation.getExtensionAttributes()Ljava/util/Map;
>       at org.apache.axis2.description.WSDL11ToAxisServiceBuilder.populateOperations(WSDL11ToAxisServiceBuilder.java:1427)
>       at org.apache.axis2.description.WSDL11ToAxisServiceBuilder.populatePortType(WSDL11ToAxisServiceBuilder.java:606)
>       at org.apache.axis2.description.WSDL11ToAxisServiceBuilder.populateEndpoints(WSDL11ToAxisServiceBuilder.java:483)
>       at org.apache.axis2.description.WSDL11ToAxisServiceBuilder.populateService(WSDL11ToAxisServiceBuilder.java:373)
>       ... 56 more

im using axis2-1.6.1 and it says java compliance level is 6
I googled it but couldn't find a relevant solution to this problem. 
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: can you post the method name in your web service provider and client (including the parameters)?

Comment: the method declaration is that ' public String SearchandDisplay(String word, String text) '

Comment: Please post exact axis2 version, and what JDK version you are using

Comment: check that the method in your web service class has `@WebService` annotation and is declarated in your wsdl

Comment: im using axis2-1.6.1 and it says java compliance level is 6

Comment: You should edit your question and post this info.

Comment: Same error here,  using axis2-1.8.0 and JDK 1.8.  Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and solved it by checking out my **WEB-INF/lib**. 
I had two of any **AXIS2** jar files in my **WEB-INF**. 
It also happens if jar files from two different versions of axis2 were copied to **WEB-INF**.

Hope it works :-)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that Eclipse "isn't finding something".

Here's one example; the solution here was to:

1. Make sure all necessary .jar libraries were included in the project
2. Select "search local classes first" in Class loading when doing a deploy

[Error in AXIS2 when i try publish ODI web services](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=855977)

Comment: i've already looked at this and since i'm really new to java, i couldn't find the "missing library", and also when i first created the service it didn't complain

Comment: Luiggi Mendoza's comment about "@WebService" annotation is good advice - please double-check it.  And Java is case-sensitive: method "myMethod()" and method "MyMethod()" are *two different things*.  If you accidentally typed one - but meant the other - the program will compile ... but might fail with a "NoSuchMethod" error at runtime.

Comment: i don't know where to check "@WebService" and the thing is i couldn't create a client so i couldn't call any function anywhere. the problem comes when i'm trying to create it. not when im calling something

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the following instructions.

1. Make Sure Your Web Service is Available in the Server. Please check it by viewing the WSDL of you web service.
2. After that follow the instructions on one of these articles,

[web-service-client-using-eclipse-axis2](http://emsooriyabandara.blogspot.com/2010/05/web-service-client-using-eclipse-axis2.html)
[BottomUpAxis2WebService](http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/community/tutorials/BottomUpAxis2WebService/bu_tutorial.html)

It works for me fine. Make sure that your code-gen plug-in is properly installed for eclipse.